# Error in reading wind speed from esp32

Tags: arduino-uno

I need your assistance with a problem I am facing. I built a weather station. esp32 board was used in this project. I used a hall sensor with a magnet in the wind speed measuring part (ANEMOMETER). Previously the method I used was **when 20 counts of magnet counted by the hall sensor, it will count the time for 20 counts and output the average wind speed**. Code worked fine with the esp32 board. But for better accuracy, I changed the method. Now the method is **within 20 seconds how many counts of the magnet were detected will be output as an average wind speed**. Since then the wind speed reading couldn't be seen on the serial monitor. ( I have the wind speed part of the code built for the Arduino Uno & it works fine with both methods). The Arduino sketch is below. The only change I did in 2 methods are

if (revolutions>=20) { was changed to if ((millis ()-timeold)==30000) {

```
    //Define all libraries in here....

#include<FirebaseESP32.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include "DHT.h"

#define FIREBASE_HOST "https://digital-weather-station-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "jbqMg4BPxhCTTicMJAXXvV3LiuFW85PZVb8e8GZY"

const char *ssid = "SVITIN-70A0";
const char *password = "10237684";
String D;

#define DHTPIN 4     
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302)
#define Offset 0;

// Connect pin 1 (on the left) of the sensor to GROUND 
// Connect pin 2 of the sensor to +3.3V
// Connect pin 3 (on the right) of the sensor to whatever your DHTPIN is

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

FirebaseData firebaseData;

//Variables For Humidity & Temperature
float h=0;  //Define Humidity value Default Value = 0
float t=0;  //Define Temp value in celcius Default Value = 0

//Variables For Wind Speed
volatile byte revolutions;
float rpmilli;
float Speed;
unsigned long timeold=0;

//Variables For Wind Direction
int VaneValue;// raw analog value from wind vane
int Direction;// translated 0 - 360 direction
int CalDirection;// converted value with offset applied
int LastValue;



//Defined new void funtion for get temp and hum...
void Temp(){
   // Wait a two seconds between measurements.
  delay(2000); // Reading temperature or humidity takes about 250 milliseconds!
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  // Read temperature as Celsius (the default)
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  

  // Check if any reads failed and exit early (to try again).
  if (isnan(h) || isnan(t)) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to read from DHT sensor!"));
    return;
  }

 
  Serial.print(F("Humidity: "));
  Serial.print(h);
  Serial.print(F("%  Temperature: "));
  Serial.print(t);
  Serial.print(F("°C "));
  

  if (Firebase.pushFloat(firebaseData, "/Weather Results/Temperature",t))
  {
    Serial.println("PASSED");
    Serial.println("PATH: " + firebaseData.dataPath());
    Serial.println("TYPE: " + firebaseData.dataType());
    Serial.println("ETag: " + firebaseData.ETag());
    Serial.println("------------------------------------");
    Serial.println();
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("FAILED");
    Serial.println("REASON: " + firebaseData.errorReason());
    Serial.println("------------------------------------");
    Serial.println();
  }

  if (Firebase.pushFloat(firebaseData, "/Weather Results/Humidity",h))
  {
    Serial.println("PASSED");
    Serial.println("PATH: " + firebaseData.dataPath());
    Serial.println("TYPE: " + firebaseData.dataType());
    Serial.println("ETag: " + firebaseData.ETag());
    Serial.println("------------------------------------");
    Serial.println();
 }
 else
 {
    Serial.println("FAILED");
    Serial.println("REASON: " + firebaseData.errorReason());
    Serial.println("------------------------------------");
    Serial.println();
  }
  }


void WSpeed(){
    // if (revolutions>=20) {
   if ((millis ()-timeold)==30000) { 
    //Update RPM every 30 seconds, increase this for better RPM resolution,
    //decrease for faster update

    // calculate the revolutions per milli(second)
    rpmilli = ((float)revolutions)/(millis()-timeold);

    timeold = millis();
    revolutions = 0;

    // WHEELCIRC = 2 * PI * radius (in meters)
    // speed = rpmilli * WHEELCIRC * "milliseconds per hour" / "meters per kilometer"

    // simplify the equation to reduce the number of floating point operations
    // speed = rpmilli * WHEELCIRC * 3600000 / 1000
    // speed = rpmilli * WHEELCIRC * 3600

    Speed = rpmilli * 0.7665 * 3600;

    Serial.print("RPM:");
    Serial.print(rpmilli * 60000);
    Serial.print(" Speed:");
    Serial.print(Speed);
    Serial.println(" kmph");
    
  if (Firebase.pushFloat(firebaseData, "/Weather Results/Speed",Speed))
  {
    Serial.println("PASSED");
    Serial.println("PATH: " + firebaseData.dataPath());
    Serial.println("TYPE: " + firebaseData.dataType());
    Serial.println("ETag: " + firebaseData.ETag());
    Serial.println("------------------------------------");
    Serial.println();
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("FAILED");
    Serial.println("REASON: " + firebaseData.errorReason());
    Serial.println("------------------------------------");
    Serial.println();
  }
  }
}

  void rpm_fun()
{
  revolutions++;
}

void WDirection(){
VaneValue = analogRead(34);
Direction = map(VaneValue, 0, 4095, 0, 360);
CalDirection = Direction + Offset;

// Only update serial monitor if change greater than 5 degrees.
if(abs(CalDirection - LastValue) > 1){
Serial.print(VaneValue); Serial.print("\t\t");
Serial.print(CalDirection); Serial.print("\t\t");
getHeading(CalDirection);
LastValue = CalDirection;
}
  }

// Converts compass direction to heading
void getHeading(int Direction) {
if(Direction < 35){
Serial.println("N");
 D="N";
}

else if (Direction < 100){
 Serial.println("NE");
 D = "NE" ;
}

else if (Direction < 170){
  Serial.println("E");
  D = "E" ;
  }

else if (Direction < 200 ){
  Serial.println("SE");
  D = "SE" ;
  }

else if (Direction < 210){
  Serial.println("S");
  D = "S" ;
  }

else if (Direction < 245){
  Serial.println("SW");
  D = "SW" ; 
  }

else if (Direction < 259){
  Serial.println("W");
  D = "W" ; 
  }

else if (Direction < 268){
  Serial.println("NW");
  D = "NW" ; 
  }

else
Serial.println();

if (Firebase.pushString(firebaseData, "/Weather Results/Wind Direction",D))
  {
    Serial.println("PASSED");
    Serial.println("PATH: " + firebaseData.dataPath());
    Serial.println("TYPE: " + firebaseData.dataType());
    Serial.println("ETag: " + firebaseData.ETag());
    Serial.println("------------------------------------");
    Serial.println();
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("FAILED");
    Serial.println("REASON: " + firebaseData.errorReason());
    Serial.println("------------------------------------");
    Serial.println();
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(F("DHTxx test!"));
  dht.begin();                                                               //DHT and TEMP sensor starting.....
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(27), rpm_fun, RISING);                // Attaching Interrupt funtion for wind speed....
  revolutions = 0;
  rpmilli = 0;
  timeold = 0;
  LastValue = 1;
  Serial.println("Vane Value\tDirection\tHeading");

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("");

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected with IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println();
  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
  Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);
}



void loop() {
  Temp();
  delay(2000);
  WSpeed();
 delay(2000);
  WDirection();
 delay(2000);
  }
```

Comment: the problem is probably the `==` ... think about it